# Alternate proof of the integral: $\int_0^1 x^x(1-x)^{2x}\,dx\neq3/8$

Tags: integration, approximation, alternative-proof

I am looking into the integral: $$I=\int_0^1 x^x(1-x)^{2x}\,dx\neq\frac{3}{8}$$

How might you prove this to be true? What's tough is that the integral $$3/8\lt I<0.37503$$ numerically. I managed to prove this by means of Riemann sums, classically, but ideas like Taylor expansion are extremely difficult in this case...

Comment: Thanks for the edit @probablyme

Comment: You say you already proved that $\frac38\lt I$, so you already proved $I\ne\frac38$, no?

Comment: @joriki, I think what Small Margin wants is an elegant proof without going into tedious numerical approximation.  Something like 'cut the integral off at this point, there the functions have that property, so bound this by that and use the other thing' and out comes an inequality $I>3/8$.  However, as the poster himself observes, 3/8 is pretty close to the actual value, so I doubt any "slick" proof will give such a good bound.  I'll be glad to be wrong.

Comment: @guest That is what makes my question so intriguiging to at least myself, eh? But yes you are correct 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a solution but approximation. First, note that $\frac{3}{8}=0.3750000000$. The function $f(x)=x^x(1-x)^{2x}$ is convex on $(0,c_1)\cup(c_2,1)$ and concave on $(c_1,c_2)$, where $c_1\approx  0.2718247$ and $c_2\approx 0.5243816$.

So that applying the hermite-hadamard inequality 
\begin{eqnarray}
f\left( {\frac{{a + b}}{2}} \right) \le \frac{1}{{b -
a}}\int\limits_a^b {f\left( x \right)dx}  \le \frac{{f\left( a
\right) + f\left( b \right)}}{2},
\end{eqnarray}
which hold for all convex functions $f$ defined on a real interval
$[a,b]$. The inequality is reversed if $f$ is concave. The inequality is sharp in both sides.

In our case $[a,b]=[0,1]$.

Therefore, On $(0,c_1)$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
 f\left( {\frac{{0 + c_1}}{2}} \right) \le \frac{1}{{c_1 -
0}}\int\limits_0^{c_1} {f\left( x \right)dx}  \le \frac{{f\left( 0
\right) + f\left( c_1 \right)}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
and we write
\begin{eqnarray}
0.1991787227\le  \int\limits_0^{c_1} {f\left( x \right)dx}  \le 0.2149827495\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)
\end{eqnarray}

On $(c_2,1)$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
0.04452261402\le \int\limits_{c_2}^{1} {f\left( x \right)dx} \le 0.07962031056\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)
\end{eqnarray}
On $(c_1,c_2)$, $f$ is concave and thus the Hermite-Hadamard inequality is reversed, then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
0.1155270131\le \int\limits_{c_1}^{c_2} {f\left( x \right)dx} \le 0.1164615612\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)
\end{eqnarray}

Adding the inequalities (1)-(3), we get

\begin{eqnarray}
0.3581809649\le \int\limits_{0}^{1} {f\left( x \right)dx} \le 0.4110646213 
\end{eqnarray}
Due to sharpness of H.-H. inequality, this is the best possible analytic  approximation even that the approximation of $c_1,c_2$ is almost accurate.

Using Maple I get the numerical solution 0.3750261533 which is not $\frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: Sorry, I've been pretty inactive on this site for a while.